# robots.txt - disallow page without querystring

Tags: linux, seo, lamp, redhat, robots.txt

I have a page that serves up dynamic content

```
/for-sale
```

the page should always have at least one parameter

```
/for-sale?id=1
```

I'd like to disallow

```
/for-sale
```

but allow

```
/for-sale?id=*
```

without affecting the bot's ability to crawl the site or the possibility of affecting negatively on SERP's.

Is this possible?

Comment: which platform, http framework, webserver and language you are using?

Comment: Linux Red Hat - LAMP Server - Apache - PHP

Comment: This is a misuse of robots.txt.  The restrictions you're talking about should be implemented at the web server level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want does not work using `robots.txt`:

1. There is no such thing as `Allow:` in the robot exclusion standard, although the RFC written by M. Koster suggests so (and *some* crawlers seem to support it).
2. No such thing as query strings or wildcards is supported, so disallowing the "naked" version will disallow everything. Surely not what you want.
3. Anything in `robots.txt` is an entirely optional, and merely a hint. No robot is required to request that file at all or respect anything you say.
4. You will almost certainly find one or several web crawlers for which any or all of the above is wrong, and you have no way of knowing.

To address the actual problem, you could put a rewrite rule into your Apache configuration file. There is readily available code available for turning an URL with query string into a normal URL ([example](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string/) from a quick web search).

(Alternatively, you could just leave the `id` query string in place. The One Search Engine that makes up 85% of your traffic eats them just fine, and the other two that make up 90% of what is not Google do as well.
So your fear is really only about search engines that nobody uses, and about spam harvesters.)

Comment: actually, I understand that not all search engines abide to special wildcard rules in robots.txt and I think you kind of missed the point of the question (I wanted to attempt to discourage access without querystring). however your information was informative. I will most likely use .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
Disallow: /for-sale    
Allow: /for-sale?id=*&*
Allow: /for-sale?id=*
```

Comment: I ran this through a checker and it warns this about *
"Besides the major search engines, most crawlers don't support wildcard matches and will most likely misunderstand or ignore them."
If you really want to do this you may need to do it in your code (vs robots.txt)